# Workday deprecated the Update_Employee_Personal_info, what replaces is?

Tags: integration, workday-api

When you look at the Workday Web Services definitions, [Human Resources V29.0](https://community.workday.com/sites/default/files/file-hosting/productionapi/Human_Resources/v29.0/Human_Resources.html) is latest as I write this, it says that Update_Employee_Personal_info call is deprecated.

When you look at some of the other deprecated calls they suggest an alternate call to use. For this one, they do not.

What is the replacement for Update_Employee_Personal_Info, now that it is deprecated?

Specifically I was looking for the Contact_Data aspect, since that contains email and phone info. Some of the personal info is available in other calls, but I cannot find phone and email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once I got a Workday community account I was about to find the news about the WWS v29.0 release (Workday Web services) and it has a section about deprecated API calls.

The note on Update_Employee_Personal_info suggests that they have moved to more granular update calls, and lists them as:

- Change Personal Info
- Change Legal Name
- Change Preferred Name
- Change Additional Name
- Change Government ID's
- Change Passports and Visa's
- Change Licenses
- Change Other ID's

Same change was made for Update_Contingent_Personal_info with similar API calls suggested instead.

The specific thing I was looking for, Phone and Email changes is in an API call Maintain_Contact_Information.

My favorite option is still Royal_Suffix_reference.  I thought that was pretty funny that it came up often enough to be required in the API as a standalone item.